# Loading values from localstorage into typescript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm making a preferences object in Typescript, and I want it to be smart enough to enforce typings in the code. Everything will be stored in localStorage which means ultimately the values will all be strings. Here's a simplified example:

```
type ONOFF = 'ON' | 'OFF';
type DIRECTION = 'NORTH' | 'SOUTH' | 'EAST' | 'WEST';

enum KEY {
  DESTINATION = 'destination',
  ORIGIN = 'origin',
  LIGHTMODE = 'lightMode',
};


interface IPreferences {
  [KEY.DESTINATION]: DIRECTION; 
  [KEY.ORIGIN]: DIRECTION;
  [KEY.LIGHTMODE]: ONOFF;
};

const defaults: IPreferences = {
  destination: 'NORTH', 
  origin: 'SOUTH', 
 lightMode: 'ON'
};
```

That works fine in code. There's autocomplete for every preference anywhere in the app.

I'm running into an issue though with loading in the values from localStorage.

```
const stored : Partial<IPreferences> = {};

Object.values(KEY).forEach((preference) => {
  const value = localStorage.getItem(preference);
  if(value) {
    stored[preference] = value;
  }
});
```

The `stored[preference] = value;` line errors with `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`.

Now I could get around this error by not looping through the available keys and hardcoding each one, ie:

```
const hardCoded : Partial<IPreferences> = {
  [KEY.DESTINATION]: localStorage.getItem(KEY.DESTINATION) as ONOFF;
}
```

but that's not ideal.

Comment: Avoid loop/assignment with Object.fromEntries: https://tsplay.dev/N9jv3m

Comment: @vr. That works, but when you write "avoid loop/assignment" are you saying not to implement your solution. ESLint doesn't complain about this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the stored object is defined as Partial, which means that its properties may be undefined. When you assign a value to stored[preference], TypeScript is inferring the type of value to be string | null, which cannot be assigned to stored[preference], since it is expected to be of type DIRECTION or ONOFF.

```
stored[preference] = value as IPreferences[typeof preference];
```

Comment: Does not work: https://tsplay.dev/w84krw Make sure to test your answer first.